# Background location updates on Android Oreo stop after 2 hours

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, google-location-services

Android 8 (Oreo) has introduced a few [Background Execution and Location limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits.html). There are 2 ways to request location updates - via a [looper](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback,%20android.os.Looper)) for foreground requests and via [pending intent](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient.html#removeLocationUpdates(android.app.PendingIntent)) (ie BroadcastReceiver) for background requests.

> If your app is running in the background, the location system service computes a new location for your app only a few times each hour.

**The problem**:
When the app goes into background mode, I receive location updates for roughly 2 hours and then none until after I actually open the app again. My LocationRequest settings do not specify any expiry times, therefore, I expected to receive the location updates indefinitely.

```
val locationRequest =  {
        val mLocationRequest = LocationRequest()
        mLocationRequest.interval = 4.minutes()
        mLocationRequest.priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY
        mLocationRequest.maxWaitTime = 10.minutes()
        mLocationRequest.fastestInterval = 30.seconds()
        mLocationRequest
    }()

val intent = Intent(this, BackgroundLocationUpdatesReceiver::class.java)
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(mContext).requestLocationUpdates(locationRequest, pendingIntent)
```

I was considering some battery optimizations to be responsible for that *(ie. Android Doze or OS putting the app in standby mode)* but other apps are sending notifications, therefore, it's not in Doze and the app being in standby doesn't matter as it is sent via PendingIntent to a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: This new feature is so bad that even Google Map's location sharing feature become useless, I can no longer get friend's current location

Answer (score 3):

Possible Solution for this will be Firebase Job Dispatcher.
You can schedule a job that will start the service after each 2 hours or 1 hours.

You logic for starting background service can vary. I am assuming this as I see whatsapp is running in background message on certain interval on my device which is having O update.

You can check out Firebase dispatcher [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9363698/pb-android)

[Other alternatives](https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c)  for background service in Oreo.

Comment: as you suggest in your answer , one should have to implement firebase job scheduler , so its kind a push to phone to start service again . am i right ? is there any other way at android side to trigger it without push from server ?

Comment: Can't believe that this could be the intended solution - what's the point of providing the background location listener if it doesn't work...